# Win7 Как посмотреть конец строки которая не влазит в поле списка?

Tags: gui, windows-7, listbox

Вот.
При наведении курсора мышки на строку, подсказка не появляется, с полным текстом названия пункта.
Нормально ли это ?
Спасибо заранее.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNrLU.jpg
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Привет бот. Это вопрос для тех кто понимает, а  не для тех кто не понимает. Ибо от вторых нет никакой пользы если они не поняли о чем речь  читая  текст названия, текст сообщения и глядя на картинку. Думаю я понятно выразился и по теме и  по твоему  выводу.